# I need a hint regarding the following problem in field extensions.

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Let $L/K$ be a field extension. Let $t$ be a transcendental element over the field $K$. Find the minimal polynomial of $t$ over $K(\frac{t^3}{2t+1})$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $s = t^3/(2t+1)$, then $t^3 - (2t+1)s = 0$.
Is that minimal?

Comment: Is there any direct way of showing it is irreducible? I am working with degree of minimal polynomial trying to show it can't be 1 or 2.

Comment: If the cubic $t^3-(2t+1)s$ is not irreducible, it has a factor that has degree $1$.